# using a conditional variable which is defined later in verilog

Tags: conditional-statements, verilog, instantiation, mux

Suppose I have the following instantiation
`first_mux_input=top.middle.down[i]; 
 second_mux_input=top.middle.down[i+1]; 
 assign down = (select[i])? first_mux_input:second_mux_input;`

supposing there are a lot of muxes and their outputs go to the inputs to muxes that are placed below them.

I'm using the variable "down" before I define it. is this legal since verilog compiles all the lines subsequently and not by order(in this case)?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The assign statement is not a declaration.  A declaration would be:

```
wire down;
```

If you never declare **down** such as this, it will be implicitly declared.
Section 6.10 of IEEE 1800-2012 states:

> If an identifier appears on the left-hand side of a continuous assignment statement, and that identifier
>   has not been declared previously in the scope where the continuous assignment statement appears or
>   in any scope whose declarations can be directly referenced from the scope where the continuous
>   assignment statement appears (see 23.9), then an implicit scalar net of default net type shall be
>   assumed. See 10.3 for a discussion of continuous assignment statements.

and then:

> See 22.8 for a discussion of control of the type for implicitly declared nets with the `default_nettype
>   compiler directive.

This (I believe) typically means a **wire** in Verilog and **logic** in SystemVerilog.

Now, as far as **using** the value before it is **assigned**, that's perfectly legal.  As long as not declared after it is used or assigned.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your synthesizer. I have worked only with Xilinx. In my case Xilinx accepts this type definition for simulation. But for synthesis you need to define a wire/reg before instantiation.